# refs in Swagger UI + NextJs 14

Tags: next.js, swagger, swagger-ui, next.js14

I'm playing with swagger in nextjs 14. I'm using next-swagger-doc package (https://github.com/jellydn/next-swagger-doc), but can't import yaml file as ref. Code used to generate swagger i almost 1:1 from example in repo, at the end I maually add schemas field.

```
export const getApiDocs = async () => {
  const spec = createSwaggerSpec({
    apiFolder: 'src/app/api', // define api folder under app folder,
    definition: {
      openapi: '3.1.0',
      servers: [
        {
          url: 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
      ],
      info: {
        title: 'API documentation',
        version: '1.0'
      },
      components: {
        securitySchemes: {
          BearerAuth: {
            type: 'http',
            scheme: 'bearer',
            bearerFormat: 'JWT'
          }
        }
      },
      security: []
    }
  })

  spec.components.schemas = {
    UserData: {
      $ref: 'index.yaml'
    }
  }
  console.log('spec', spec.components.schemas)
  return spec
}
```

index.yaml is in the same folder as getApiDocs function an it only contains one line for testing
`type: string`

Visiting my doc endpoint shows swagger ui, but schemas section cant load yaml properly
[image: missing value]

and there is error shown
[image: error]

I tried to change path for file in this ref (./index.yaml, index.yaml, /index.yaml, src/app/api/_apidoc/index.yaml), tried different file name.

Is there something I'm missing?